# Python script to automate software installation in windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, automation

I have a set of 14 softwares that should be installed in over 10 windows machine.
Few of these softwares are custom bild which are saved in a shared folder.These custom bild apps should be installed locally in a specific path.
The rest of the sotwares should be downloded from the internet and installed accordingly.

I would like to automate this process.

Could someone suggest me any code samples or tutorial.

Comment: looks like you need `Ansible` https://www.ansible.com/resources/get-started

Comment: @Rakesh thankyou but does it support windows?

Comment: Yes it does, only condition is that the control node should be a linux box